# Can I set the Linux coredump file format for current current process only?

Tags: linux

Some help file introduce to use sysctl, but it would changed the format globally and need admin permission to do, is there any API or a way to change the dump format for current process only in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The core format is not specified in the process table, and hence it is not possible to change it per-process. Use the [pipe core handler](http://lwn.net/Articles/195310/) to filter the cores and handle them as desired. See the `core(5)` man page for details.